# How to use a GitHub as a hosting for a small static website?

Tags: hosting, github

I have found a project called [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js) on GitHub.

This project has a cool demo at http://impress.github.io/impress.js/.

How can I use GitHub in a similar way for my projects' demos (or at least for HTML-formatted online docs)?

Comment: While some questions about GitHub might be on-topic here, questions about creating / managing websites are off-topic. They might be asked in [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are called [GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/272-github-pages). [Here](http://pages.github.com/) are the details on how to set it up.

1. #### Create a repository

   Head over to GitHub and create a new repository named username.github.io, where username is your username (or organization name) on GitHub.
   If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.
2. #### Clone the repository
3. #### Hello World

   Enter the project folder and add an index.html file: